# Unable to re-add the office 365 owners inside the sharepoint site collection admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

I have create a new Private sharepoint team site named TestUserPer1, where by default i will get this group added as site collection admin:-

[image]

Now i mistakenly remove the above group from the site collection admin, so i tried to re-add it again, but the auto-complete did not return any entity named "TestUserPer1 Owners" ... any advice (i only get "TestUserPer1 Members")?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to the sharepoint online admin center, select the site. Click Permissions in the Info panel, if the group is disconnected from the admins role, a message box will show up with a link to reconnect it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This value is automatically set by Microsoft. You may need to wait for a synchronisation to occur for it to be re-added, or making a change to the Microsoft 365 group owners may cause it to synchronise. If this does not occur and you are unable to re-add the group, you may need to open a ticket with Microsoft through the Microsoft 365 portal.

Comment: i do not think this value is suppose to be synced

Comment: I think you should take a look at Michael Han_MSFT's answer. If that doesn't work then you may need to open a ticket with Microsoft.